# Perl --Change in all matches in previous lines according to match in current line

Tags: perl, multiline

File I want to parse:

```
input Pattern;

input SDF;

input ABC

input Pattern;

output Pattern;

output XYZ;
```

In perl, usual operation is scan line by line.
I want to check that if 
current line has `output Pattern;` and previous line (or all previous lines)has `input Pattern;` 
then change all the previous lines matches to `"input Pattern 2;"` and current line to `"output Pattern2;"`.

It is complicated ,I hope I have explained properly.
Is it possible in Perl to scan and change previous lines after they have been read?

Thanks

Comment: It will be great if you show input and desired output.

Comment: In the example, are both `input Pattern;` suppose to change to `input Pattern 2;`? You said it should, but I want to confirm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is your data:

```
my $sfile =
'input Pattern;
input SDF;
input ABC
input Pattern;
output Pattern;
output XYZ;' ;
```

then, the following snippet will read the whole file and change text  accordingly:

```
open my $fh, '<', \$sfile or die $!;
local $/ = undef;                # set file input mode to 'slurp'
my $content = <$fh>;
close $fh;

$content =~ s{ (                   # open capture group
                input \s+ (Pattern); # find occurence of input pattern
                .+?                  # skip some text
                output \s+ \2        # find same for output
               )                   # close capture group
             }
             {                     # replace by evaluated expression
              do{                    # within a do block
                 local $_=$1;        # get whole match to $_
                 s/($2)/$1 2/g;      # substitute Pattern by Pattern 2
                 $_                  # return substituted text
                }                    # close do block
             }esgx;
```

Then, you may close your file and check the string:

```
print $content;
```

=>

```
input Pattern 2;
input SDF;
input ABC
input Pattern 2;
output Pattern 2;
output XYZ;
```

---

You may even include a counter `$n` which will be incremented after each successful match (by code assertion `(?{ ... })`:

```
our $n = 1;

$content =~ s{ (                   # open capture group
                input \s+ (Pattern); # find occurence of input pattern
                .+?                  # skip some text
                output \s+ \2        # find same for output
                )                  # close capture group
                (?{ $n++ })        # ! update match count 
             }
             {                     # replace by evaluated expression
              do{                    # within a do block
                 local $_=$1;        # get whole match to $_
                 s/($2)/$1 $n/g;     # substitute Pattern by Pattern and count
                 $_                  # return substituted text
                }                  # close do block
             }esgx;
```

The substitution will now start with `input Pattern 2;` und increment subsequently.

Comment: Thanks ...Sometime we convert EASY problem to HARD problem....By Long Thinking,,,,and USING Heavy Words like,,,,multiline scanning...scan sevral lines together,etc...It is right for per "There are more then one way to do it"

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

$in1 = 'input Pattern';
$in2 = 'input Pattern2';
$out1 = 'output Pattern';
$out2 = 'output Pattern2';

undef $/;
$_ = <DATA>;
if (/^$in1\b.*?^$out1\b/gms) {
    s/(^$in1\b)(?=.*?^$out1\b)/$in2/gms;
    s/^$out1\b/$out2/gms;
}
print;

__DATA__
input Pattern;
input SDF;
input ABC;
input Pattern;
output Pattern;
output XYZ;
```

Comment: Will this work? If the pattern is found on line 10, how is your code substituting all instances of the said text in the previous 9 lines?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot go back and change lines in Perl. What you can do is open the file for the first time in `read` mode, find out which line has the pattern (say the 5th line), close it before gulping the entire file into an array, open it again in `write` mode, modify the contents of the array upto the 5th line, dump that array into that file, and close it. Something like this (assuming each file will have at most one **output pattern**):

```
my @arr;
my @files = ();
while (<>) {
    if ($. == 0) {
        $curindex = undef;
        @lines    = ();
        push @files, $ARGV;
    }
    push @lines, $_;
    if (/output pattern/) { $curindex = $. }
    if (eof) {
        push @arr, [\@lines, $curindex];
        close $ARGV;
    }
}

for $file (@files) {
    open file, "> $file";
    @currentfiledetails  = @{ $arr[$currentfilenumber++] };
    @currentcontents     = @{ $currentfiledetails[0] };
    $currentoutputmarker = $currentfiledetails[1];
    if ($currentoutputmarker) {
        for (0 .. $currentoutputmarker - 2) {
            $currentcontents[$_] =~ s/input pattern/input pattern2/g;
        }
        $currentcontents[$currentoutputmarker - 1] =~
            s/output pattern/output pattern2/g;
    }
    print file for @currentcontents;
    close file;
}
```

Comment: You cannot go back and change lines <del>in Perl</del><ins>period</ins> because of the nature of files. (Although Tie::File sure makes it look like you can :) )

Comment: Well, that's what I said in my answer, didn't I?

Comment: No. You said the limitation was a Perl limitation, while I said it wasn't. Also, you didn't mention Tie::File, and I did.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know Tie::File can do such stuff. Thanks. But I think underneath the interface Tie::File provides, what it does is kind of similar to what I did.

Comment: @Cupidvogel: `Tie::File` is far more clever than that. It maintains a cache of part of the file which it pages in and out of memory according to usage. The location of all file records in cache is kept so that they can be accessed promptly.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do what you need, but **try it on a 'scratch' file first (a copy of the original)** since it actually changes the file:

```
use Modern::Perl;

open my $fh_in, '<', 'parseThis.txt' or die $!;
my @fileLines = <$fh_in>;
close $fh_in;

for ( my $i = 1 ; $i < scalar @fileLines ; $i++ ) {
    next
      if $fileLines[$i] !~ /output Pattern;/
          and $fileLines[ $i - 1 ] !~ /input Pattern;/;
    $fileLines[$i] =~ s/output Pattern;/output Pattern2;/g;
    $fileLines[$_] =~ s/input Pattern;/input Pattern 2;/g for 0 .. $i - 1;
}

open my $fh_out, '>', 'parseThis.txt' or die $!;
print $fh_out @fileLines;
close $fh_out;
```

Results:

```
input Pattern 2;
input SDF;
input ABC;
input Pattern 2;
output Pattern2;
output XYZ;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: For big files, this is going to be crazy inefficient. For small files, you might as load the file into memory.

Comment: @ikegami - In the original code, I failed to consider the (possibly intense) Tie::File I/O on big files resulting from multiple substitutions.  The above fixes that.  Thanks for bringing this to my attention.

Comment: The problem is inherent to using Tie::File for the job. There's no reason to read the file more than twice, yet that's the *minimum* your code needs (i.e. if you do no substitutions). Then you start adding substitutions that can potentially rewrite the entire file...

Answer (score 0):

Will there be additional "Input pattern1: lines folloring an occurence of "Output Patttern1?"

1. Are there going to be multiple pattern to search for, or will it just be "If we find Output Pattern1 then perform the replacement?
2. Will the "output pattern occur multiple times, or just once?
3. Will there be additional "Input pattern1: lines folloring an occurence of "Output Patttern1?"

I would perform this task in two/mutiple passes:

1. Pass1 - read the file, looking for the matching output lines, store the line number in memory.
2. Pass 2 - read the file, and based on the line numbers in the set of matches, perform the replacement on the appropriate Input lines.

So in semi-perlish, untested psuedocode:

```
my @matches = ();
open $fh, $inputfile, '<';
while (<$fh>) {
   if (/Pattern1/) {
     push @matches, $.;
   }
}
close $fh;

open $fh, $inputfile, '<';
while (<$fh>) {
  if ($. <= $matches[-1]) {
    s/Input Pattern1/Input Pattern2/;
    print ;
  }
  else {
    pop @matches);
    last unless @matches;
  }
}
close $fh;
```

You run this like:

```
      $ replace_pattern.pl input_file > output_file
```

You'll need to adjust it a little to meet your exact needs, but that should get you close.